# How to source css from Magento_Theme /web instead of theme root /web?

Tags: magento2, theme, css, js-css

I am trying to include a CSS from a jQuery library that I have within `Magento_Theme/web/js/libs/` folder, however, I am struggling to source a CSS file from within here?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme/web/js/libs/slick/styles.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

How can I do this? I can only seem to source css from within the `root/web` folder within my theme if I was to use:

```
<css src="css/styles.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this but give this a try:

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::js/libs/slick/slick.css" />
```

All I've done is remove `web` as it isn't required, and changed `/` to `::` (that you noticed xD)

Comment: Thanks Ben, the above code didn't work but pointed me in the right direction :) I changed it to follow the same structure as adding blocks :) See my answer....

Comment: FML, I forget that the `/` should be `::` at least once a week.  I'll update this even though you've already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working :)

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::js/libs/slick/slick.css" />
```